# Setting different priority for each term in a sentence in Solr

Tags: search, solr

I have a search sentence like the following:

```
philips led bulb
```

I want to set different priorities for each word: `bulb` priority is 8, `led` priority is 7 and `philips` priority is 6. How can do I that with Solr?

Answer (score 0):

The standard query parser (and edismax, etc.) supports giving weights for each term, using the `^<weight>` syntax: `bulb^8 led^7 philips^6`.

If you want to apply different weights to different "categories" of words, index the words to different fields and use `qf` to query all the fields. `qf` also supports the `^<weight>` syntax, so you can apply a query as `categories^8 manufacturer^6` etc.